# I can’t rename partitions in macOS

Tags: disk-utility, partition

I’ve created a thumbdrive with 12 partitions with ASD EFI tests for Macs.

I tried renaming the partitions to shorter names with both Finder and Disk utility (so they show up in startup manager properly, the instead appear with this "EFI BOOT" name, see picture).  The problem is that the names of the partitions in Startup Manager is different to the one I put.

I also tried renaming them with this command (to no avail):
/usr/sbin/diskutil rename ASDEFI124 42
(where 42 is the new name I want to set)

I also remember that in older versions of macOS, such as Yosemite or earlier, when you restored the image in disk utility, it gave you the option to set a name for the new partition and that seemed to work.  But I can see this is not offered in macOS 10.11 nor in macOS 10.14.

Any way to rename them to this shorter names?

I'd like shorter names here, like 40 41, 43...
[image]